# Props passed from parent to child and setting those props in state does not work immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am building an app where I get "complaints" from my Nodejs app. Then I pass those complaints to child component as props. In child component, I set those props to state in `ComponentDidMount()`. But `render()` function gets called first so it does not show anything on screen. State is not set immediately. please help. I am struggling from 2 days.

this is parent component

```
class Complainer extends Component {
  state = {
    complaints: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
      console.log(user);
      this.setState({ user });
      if (!user || user.role !== 'complainer') this.props.history.replace('/');
    } catch (ex) {
      window.location = '/login';
    }

    const { data: complaints } = await getComplaints();
    this.setState({ complaints });
  }

  render() {
    const { complaints } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar user={this.state.user} />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/complainer/view-all"
              render={props => (
                <AllComplaints complaints={complaints} {...props} />
              )}
            />
            <Route path="/complainer/new-complaint" component={ComplaintForm} />
            <Route path="/complainer/not-found" component={notfound} />
            <Showcase user={this.state.user} />
          </Switch>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Complainer;
```

This is child

```
class AllComplaints extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      columns: [
        {
          label: 'location',
          field: 'location',
          sort: 'asc',
          width: 280
        },
        {
          label: 'Title',
          field: 'title',
          sort: 'asc',
          width: 150
        }
      ],

      rows: []
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { complaints } = this.props;
    this.setState({ rows: complaints });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {data.rows && <MDBDataTable striped bordered small data={data} />}
        {!data.rows && <h1>There is no complaints to show</h1>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AllComplaints;
```

The problem is, as in state, rows are empty .i.e. []. in `componentDidMount()` I am setting the coming props to state of this "AllComplaints" component.

I want to set the "props" value to "this.state.data.rows". But this is not happening. It takes time to set but `render()` is called first so it shows nothing on the screen.

Please help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the state here?  Why not just use `<MDBDataTable data={this.props.complaints} />`?  Also, where is your data being retrieved? Is it in the parent's `componentDidMount`?  If so, you should include the parent's `componentDidMount` and `render` functions in your question.

Comment: i have included parent now. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

As @karahan mentioned, you're not setting your state correctly.

```
this.setState({ rows: complaints });
```

should be something like:

```
this.setState(prevState => { data: { ...prevState.data, rows: complaints } });
```

This probably won't be sufficient however.  You're retrieving your data in `componentDidMount` of the parent, and setting your state in `componentDidMount` of the child.  However, the `componentDidMount` of the child is always run first if they're mounted at the same time, and is only run once.  This means that with your setup, your child's `props.complaints` has the potential to be empty in `componentDidMount`.

I'd solve this by not using state in your child's component.  There's rarely a good reason to store the same state in multiple components (in this case, you're storing the same thing in both the parent and the child).  Just use your props, which will always be up-to-date in your render function.  Your rendering of `MDBDataTable` should probably look something like this:

```
<MDBDataTable striped bordered small data={{ ...this.state.data, rows: this.props.complaints }} />
```

If you absolutely must store `complaints` in the state of the child for some reason, you should either fetch the data in the child instead, or look into `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentDidUpdate`.  However, its unlikely that you need such a setup.

Comment: <MDBDataTable striped bordered small data={{ ...this.state.data, rows: this.props.complaints }} /> . this worked for me. thanks alot mate! thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do not set `this.state.data.rows` but `this.state.rows` and use `this.state.data.rows` inside render

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use complains during render function you need to initialise it in your state itself.

you need to write constructor for your class that accepts props from parent component and use it to define initial state of rows.

```
class AllComplaints extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state  = {
            data: {
              columns: [
                {
                  label: 'location',
                  field: 'location',
                  sort: 'asc',
                  width: 280
                },
                {
                  label: 'Title',
                  field: 'title',
                  sort: 'asc',
                  width: 150
                }
              ],

              rows: props.complaints
            }
          };
        }
          componentDidMount() {
//commeting below lines as you do not need them as of now.
            //const { complaints } = this.props;
            //this.setState({ rows: complaints });
          }

          render() {
            const { data } = this.state;
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                {data.rows && <MDBDataTable striped bordered small data={data} />}
                {!data.rows && <h1>There is no complaints to show</h1>}
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          }
        }

        export default AllComplaints;
```